# Drawing dashed edges in a binary tree and adding new edges between different nodes

Tags: nodes, tikz-trees, tikz-node, edge

I would like to add extra edges between nodes that aren't specifically related as child and parents in a binary tree and also to change the styling of the edges.

Currently I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\title{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
  every node/.style = {minimum width = 2em, draw, circle},
  level/.style = {sibling distance = 30mm/#1}
  ]
  \node{u.p}
  child {node {u}
    child{node {u.e}}
    child {edge from parent[draw = none]}
  }
  child {node {u.p.d}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

And this is giving me the following output:

[image]

Now, my desired output would be to have dashed edges between *u* and *u.p* and between *u* and *u.e* and also an extra edge connecting *u.e* to *u.p*, if possible in red, i.e., something like this:

[image]

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you use the `forest` package, which makes these modifications relatively easy.

[image]

If you want the nodes to be different sizes you can get rid of the `minimum width` setting. For the red arc, if you want it to come out of the "west" of the `u.p` node, you can try `\draw[red](up.west) to[bend right] (ue);`. Otherwise you can adjust the looseness as in the code below, or use `out=` and `in=` as for ordinary tikz lines.

In `forest`, sibling distance is controlled by `s sep=`, generation distance is controlled by `l sep=`. Individual nodes can be moved from their calculated position by adjusting their true `x` and `y` coordinates as I did for the node `u.e`. Otherwise it would be placed directly below the `u` node.

To draw additional edges, `name` the nodes and then use ordinary tikz drawing commands.

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
    for tree={draw, circle, inner sep=2pt, minimum width=1cm, font=\small, s sep=1cm}
    [u.p, name=up
        [u,edge=dashed
            [u.e, edge=dashed, before drawing tree={x-=1cm}, name=ue]]
        [u.p.d]]
    \draw[red](up) to[bend right, looseness=1.5] (ue);
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had a look at `forest` package and it seems to do the work better! The code worked for me, exactly what I wanted.